# How to handle Vue "el" pointer with multiple layouts (Laravel MPA)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So i have a laravel application that i built and is live using Laravel without Vue.js. Now, finding out about vue.js and its lightweight + numerous additional features for improved user experience, i have decided to include it and rebuild my app into components with much better reactivity.

The only issue is, with my little research, i found out that the main vue element in the resources/js/app.js points to an #app element in views/layouts/app.blade.php which would be fine if perhaps i had an SPA or and MPA that starts from there.

However, in my implementation i have different layout files for both back end and user section of my app, and i don't know how to go about it ( which element to point the vue object to).

Here's what i would like to have though, if possible. I would want a commons.js to have all my common components and imports and perhaps a [page].js for pages where i would need a bit more.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to handle this.

The Vue instance created in the app.js doesn't have to be your only instance. In MPA's you will most like have multiple vue instances, perhaps on per page. To keep my code clean, i kept the dependencies common to my whole application in app.js.

For my portals, each portal has a commons.js which containts dependencies specific to the management of my application and hence dont need to be loaded when the user is surfing my up. I set to bundle with webpack and include in all portal pages.

Furthermore, each page has a page.js which is also bundled and included only page specific dependencies (components etc) and a vue instance for each page.

By using this architecture i reduce the JS needed to be loaded to only the necessary on both portal pages and the main app for users.

Hope this helps someone! Happy coding.